# DevExpress XtraReports ReportToolbar breaks on upgrade to .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, reporting, devexpress

I just upgraded a site to .NET 4 which is using the XtraReports reports, and now the toolbar has stopped working.  Specifically, it renders ok except that it displays blank instead of the current page in the page dropdownlist, and clicking on any of the buttons in the toolbar does nothing.  Is this a known issue with a known workaround/fix?  Thanks for any pointers.  We are using version 7.3.6 of XtraReports.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to v10.1 seems to have solved the issue.  There's a known issue involving adding the TableName to the DataMember property of all reports that's a breaking change that happened sometime between v7 and v10, detailed here:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S133843.aspx